# N consecutive values screen in Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, trading

I'm looking at making a trading algo which gives a "1" signal if the last n entries in a column are "True". How would the code here look for the lookback window- can't quite find anything similar on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you [roll](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! what have you tried till now? do you have some limitation like runtime & memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) together with [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) (sum on number of `True` values within rolling window), [`.ge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) (greater than or equal to `n`) and finally [`.astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) (to convert result of `.ge()` `True/False` value to `0/1` value) as follows:

```
df['signal'] = df['Event'].rolling(n).sum().ge(n).astype(int)
```

Fulfillment of number of count of `True` >= `n` within a rolling window of (same) size `n` automatically ensures the last `n` consecutive values are all `True`.

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Number": np.arange(1,9),
    "Event": [False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]
})

n=2
df['signal'] = df['Event'].rolling(n).sum().ge(n).astype(int)

print(df)

   Number  Event  signal
0       1  False       0
1       2   True       0
2       3   True       1
3       4   True       1
4       5  False       0
5       6   True       0
6       7   True       1
7       8  False       0


n=3
df['signal'] = df['Event'].rolling(n).sum().ge(n).astype(int)


print(df)

   Number  Event  signal
0       1  False       0
1       2   True       0
2       3   True       0
3       4   True       1
4       5  False       0
5       6   True       0
6       7   True       0
7       8  False       0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "col2": [False, False, True, True, True]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1,2,3,4,5],
    "col2": [False, False, False, False, False]
})

def check_last_n(df, n):
    return (df["col2"].tail(n) == True).all()

print(check_last_n(df, 3))
print(check_last_n(df, 4))
print(check_last_n(df2, 2))
>>> True
>>> True
>>> False
```